# SSRS set Date to Computer settings

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

my current date column is set to  `*2000-01-32` and the asterisk will reflect the regional settings of the report but I would rather it look at the current culture/Computer date formatting.

Can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about getting the local date or the local date *format*? The format is controlled by the Language property of the Report or Textbox (if different from Report), which, for HTML reports, can be set to the local browser language using the built-in field `User!Language`. If you don't specify a language then the locale of the Report Server operating system is used.

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159642.aspx

Comment: Hi @Nathan, I'm referring to computer settings, the clients machine could be '2015-12-09' or '12-09-2015' or '09-12-2015' and the report should be consistent to the machine setting.

Comment: You can't use the format settings of the local computer. As noted you can reference the language of the *browser*, which may or may not be the same as the operating system. The "language" setting affects the date format used amongst other things (e.g. currency format).